# There is a finite commutative ring which has maximal ideal but not prime ideal. Is it true or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In an infinite ring 2Z , for the subring 4Z the  result is true.when we come into finite case  the result is false. So here I have failed to prove it false in arbitrarily.

Comment: The maximal elements of the poset of ideals in a ring without identity aren't as nice as in the ones with identity. For this reason, usually something is added to the definition of "maximal" in rings without identity.

Answer (score 2):

Take basically any proper, non-trivial, non-maximal ideal of your ring, and quotient out by it. Like $2\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$.  Then $4\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$ is still maximal.

Comment: It is for finite case. But you had given for infinite case....please help me with the finite example...

Comment: Those are finite rings.

Comment: @SubhajitSaha The ring $2\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$ has four elements. It is very much finite.

Comment: 